# Angular material tooltip problem with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a table with tooltips inside rows:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="icons">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <span [matTooltip]="'Hello, world'" matTooltipPosition="below"
        >tooltip</span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

The table can have thousands of rows, that's why I have to use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. However, with such detection strategy I have a problem with tooltips - they are shown without text. StackBlitz demo is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tooltip-and-changedetectionstrategy-onpush?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Could anyone say how to fix it?

Comment: I think it's much better if you avoid touching changeDetection logic (except changeDetectionStrategy). If you do that the tooltips appears perfectly. In case it starts lagging after rendering thousands of rows then you can use Angular Scrolling CDK (it's like a virtual/infinite scrolling -- a way of rendering rows in a more efficient way): https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

Comment: As @PedroBezanilla pointed out, it's not due to `OnPush` but rather you detaching the cdr from the tree. If you do this, directive won't get notified about the tooltip content. You could possibly work around it by re-attaching the cdr on hover and detaching it again afterwards. Personally I wouldn't go this way unless you REALLY know what you're doing.

Comment: Also if you just replace your ngContentInit for ngAfterViewChecked tooltips will work, cuz u are not letting Angular check the content projected into the component. But yeah, it's better if you don't touch changeDetection logic unless you know what you are really doing, as said above.